# Why are infinitesimal shifts sufficient to prove that a symmetry holds?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, lie-algebra, noethers-theorem

Why are infinitesimal shifts in the Lagrangian sufficient to prove that a symmetry holds? Couldn't a lot of things happen at higher orders? Especially when I am introducing an infinitesimal shift of a non-commuting operator?

Comment: Analogy: say a function has all partial derivatives equal to 0 everywhere. Then it is constant. Now imagine a gauge Lie group acting on your observables. That is, each observable is a function over the gauge Lie group. It suffices to show that it’s partial derivatives (variations wrt Lie algebra generators) vanish to establish that it is constant (at least over the connected component of the gauge Lie group which contains the identity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how these things appear in QFT, but if a "classical" answer is sufficient to you, then here are several things:

- First of all, you need to tell us what do you mean on "symmetry holds". For the purposes of Noether's theorem, what you need is a *Lie algebra representation* of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ on the target space $V$ of a field $\psi$ (here I consider a field to be a map from spacetime to a fixed target space - for "global" symmetries to make sense, the field must be a section of a trivial vector bundle, so this is fine). You can basically forget about Lie groups, because Noether's theorem doesn't care about them. It's just usually what you have is a Lie group representation on the target space, and Noether's theorem applies to the tangent map of this representation (eg. the corresponding Lie algebra representation).
- The infinitesimal invariance actually implies finite invariance. To simplify the derivation, let us consider a "Lagrangian" that only depends on the field but *not* the field derivatives. This doesn't change our results, just makes it easier to calculate. $$ \\ $$ Let $\phi_\epsilon$ be a one-parameter subgroup of $G$ (our symmetry group) and let $\psi\mapsto\phi_\epsilon(\psi)$ be it's linear action on the field via the representation. Obviously we have due to the homomorphism property $$\phi_\epsilon(\phi_\tau(\psi))=\phi_{\epsilon+\tau}(\psi).$$ The variation of the Lagrangian is defined as $$\delta\mathcal L(\psi)=\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\mathcal L(\phi_\epsilon(\psi))|_{\epsilon=0}.$$ Assume that this variation vanishes (for simplicity, I am ignoring the case when the Lagrangian turns into a total divergence) for any $\psi$ and any one-parameter subgroup. Then the $\epsilon$-derivative also vanishes, when evaluated at anywhere, not just at 0. To see this, consider $$ \frac{d}{d\epsilon}\mathcal L(\phi_\epsilon(\psi))|_{\epsilon=\epsilon}=\frac{d}{d\tau}\mathcal L(\phi_\tau(\phi_\epsilon(\psi)))|_{\tau=0}=\delta\mathcal L(\phi_\epsilon(\psi)).$$ But we said that the variation vanishes at *any* field, including the field $\psi^\prime=\phi_\epsilon(\psi)$, so the above vanishes. $$\\$$ Hence, we obtain that if a Lagrangian is infinitesimally symmetric under $G$, it also satisfies $$\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\mathcal L(\phi_\epsilon(\psi))=0$$ for any one-parameter subgroup and field, with this derivative evaluated everywhere. But we know that a differentiable function whose derivative vanishes everywhere must be constant everywhere. Hence we also obtain that $$ \mathcal L(\psi)=\mathcal L(\phi_\epsilon(\psi)) $$ for any $\epsilon$ (and also one-parameter subgroup and field, etc.). $$\\$$ Now this result is strictly speaking only guaranteed for group elements that can be reached by a one-parameter subgroup. So given $G$, we can form $G^\prime=\exp(\mathfrak g)$, and what we have obtained is that if the Lagrangian is infinitesimally symmetric under $\mathfrak g$, then it is also finitely symmetric under $G^\prime=\exp(\mathfrak g)$. However most groups in physics that are considered for Noether symmetries, are such that all elements can be reached from the Lie algebra via exponentialization.